# Is it correct and natural to the verb "reinforce" in the sense of improving a skill or the knowledge of something?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Could you tell me if it is correct and natural to the verb "reinforce" in the sense of improving a skill or the knowledge of something? For example:

> You might want to go back over the words again to **reinforce** the knowledge of them.
>
> You pronunciation is good, but to **reinforce** it, say that again.

If it sounds off, could you tell what you would say?

Comment: 'Consolidate'  ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## It is perfectly correct and natural to use *Reinforce* in this way.

That use of *reinforce* would be very commonly heard in a learning environment (in a classroom or with a teacher, for example).

Small unrelated correction, though: The article *the* should instead be a possessive pronoun since you're talking about a specific person's knowledge, not an abstract general knowledge of the words:

> You might want to go back over the words again to reinforce **your** knowledge of them.

Answer (score 1):

Oh absolutely. In particular, it has the sense of doing something *repeatedly* in order to improve knowledge. Using flash cards, for example. You use flash cards to strengthen (i.e., to *reinforce*) knowledge that you've already learned.